# Defined keyframe animation not working on hover

Tags: css, css-animations

I am attempting to implement an animation upon the hover state of a class element, however, it appears to be non-functional. Code is provided below .

```
.glass{
    background: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 0.75rem,
        var(--color-3) 2rem
    );
   
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(.65rem);
    filter: contrast(1.35);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    inset: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-size: 2.5rem 100%;
    /* animation: mymove 5s infinite; */
}

@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {background-size: 2.5rem 100%;}
    25%  {background-size: 2.5rem 75%;}
    75%  {background-size: 2.5rem 25%;}
    100% {background-size: 2.5rem 0%;}
}


.glass:hover {
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    /* transition: 0.7;
    opacity: 1; */
}
```

The applied glass effect should disappear gradually on hover .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering that you added this css variable in root

```
:root {
  --color-3: red;
}
```

try adding the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` it will help you to see the animation working.

```
.glass{
    background: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 0.75rem,
        var(--color-3) 2rem
    );
   
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(.65rem);
    filter: contrast(1.35);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    inset: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-size: 2.5rem 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   /* add this line */
}
```